# Square up php create card using php sdk api - card nonce error

Tags: php, square

I have tried to fix this issue but unable to do so. Field 'card_nonce' is not found on the server although it is recently created. I have used npm and node to generate a card_nonce.

Code Used:

```
$billing_address = new Address();
$billing_address->setAddressLine1('500 Electric Ave');
$billing_address->setAddressLine2('Suite 600');
$billing_address->setLocality('New York');
$billing_address->setAdministrativeDistrictLevel1('NY');
$billing_address->setPostalCode('10003');
$billing_address->setCountry('AU');

// $body = new CreateCustomerCardRequest($_POST['nonce']);
$body = new CreateCustomerCardRequest('CBASECw9ri-7s1THlCWDoSVsVY8');
$body->setBillingAddress($billing_address);
$body->setCardholderName('Gaurav Gulati');

$api_response = $customersApi->createCustomerCard($customer_id, $body);

if ($api_response->isSuccess()) {
$result = $api_response->getResult();
$customer_card = $api_response->getCard();
$customer_card_id = $customer_card->getId();
    
} else {
    $errors = $api_response->getErrors();
}
```

Response:

```
[0] => Square\Models\Error Object
(
 [category:Square\Models\Error:private] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
 [code:Square\Models\Error:private] => NOT_FOUND
 [detail:Square\Models\Error:private] => Resource not found.
 [field:Square\Models\Error:private] => card_nonce
)
```

Anyone has idea how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You've removed the "cnon:" from the parameter. "CBASECw9ri-7s1THlCWDoSVsVY8" should be `cnon:CBASECw9ri-7s1THlCWDoSVsVY8`.